# Controlling XL6009 / XL6019 DC-DC buck/booster Enable pin via Arduino

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter

I'm trying to use a [XL6009e1 based module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32835716087.html) with an arduino to control whether the input voltage, or the boosted voltage is sent on output.

As per the [XL6009 Datasheet](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/XL6009-Datasheet.pdf) or [XL6019 Datasheet](http://www.xlsemi.com/datasheet/XL6019%20datasheet-English.pdf), the ENable pin 2 is tied/floating high with VIN. For the chip to be disabled, it needs to be 0.8v or below, or 1.4v or higher to be enabled (default).

Currently I have one of these DC-DC modules, and have disconnected the second pin from the board.

Here's my question - With a 12v input on VIN, what exactly do I need to do so I can control the output by the enable pin by setting an arduino pin high or low? Obviously I can't connect Enable pin 2 directly to a GPIO since it's outputting 12v, and will fry something on the arduino. But where I'm quite confused is what exactly I can use, and secondly how I'd connect it up.

Even if I didn't have the Arduino, how exactly would I pull this pin "low"? I thought perhaps connecting directly to GND but I feel like I'm confusing something else here. I imagine using a pull down resistor, but how exactly would this be connected?

To be clear, I want to bypass the regulator and have the 12V input flow to the output when the regulator is off.

Answer (score 1):

> *Here's my question - With a 12v input on VIN, what exactly do I need
> to do so I can control the output by the enable pin by setting an
> arduino pin high or low?*

Use an NPN BJT like this: -

[image]

A 10 kΩ resistor will be fine.

Comment: Hey thanks.
I just realized I failed to mention when the enable pin is LOW, I want 12v to flow through to output. I got the impression from [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308143/reduce-current-flowing-into-a-switch-by-using-xl6009-enable-pin) that this is what should occur when voltage is low.

So i.e. desired behavior going between 12V and boosted voltage (14V) controlled via Arduino.

I've tried a 2N2222 NPN BJT with a 10k resistor to the Arduino, but I'm finding when Enable is low (and being tied to GND) I've got no voltage on output.

Comment: 12 volts will flow through to the output when the chip is disabled. Look at the circuit and tell me what can prevent this happening.

Comment: I'm certainly pretty stumped. I just realized I linked to the module I'm waiting for in the post. The actual module I have right now is [DSN6000AUD](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32835716087.html). While the layout is slightly different, I can't understand why VIN doesn't parse through with EN low.

Comment: Well, your question is pretty clear and if in fact you meant to ask about something else that doesn't appear to have a data sheet or schematic then that's an impossibility for me to foresee. You appear to have failed to mention one thing and then linked to the wrong module. Not a very effective start on this site. I suggest you ask a new question about the module you have just mentioned but only if you can find a data sheet for it or a schematic. If you can't find any data sheet or schematic then nobody's going to be able to answer.

Comment: @andy it seems this is the proper schematic https://image.easyeda.com/histories/bbe60e1ccba4432e87910b64d3f4a049.png from https://easyeda.com/johngr/xl6009-buck-boost-converter or similar https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/buck-boost-regulator-using-xl6009-with-adjustable-33v-to-12v-output-voltage. There is an inline capacitor between two of the three inductors, wouldn't that block the flow?

Comment: @Passerby I dunno; it's up to the op to supply a schematic and he doesn't look like he's coming to the table any more.